# Cross-Platform Read/Write of Extended Attributes using Rust?

Tags: file, rust, attributes, cross-platform

I'm in the process of designing software to associate custom tags to image files. My first instinct was to create a file record that associated file directories to tags, but this would become an issue if the file is moved, renamed, etc so I'm looking into alternate implementations, such as inodes/file ids or attaching data to files using Alternate Data Streams or Extended Attributes. Attaching data seems more robust, but ADS is NTFS specific thus not cross-platform, so EAs appear to be the best option. However, I'm struggling to find resources on read/writing them using Rust.

I've found [this crate](https://crates.io/crates/xattr) which supports Linux (and others, but not Windows)
The Rust std file system library includes [some methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/fs/trait.OpenOptionsExt.html) that affect permissions for writing to EAs, but I can't find anything on actually accessing them programmatically.

Comment: It appears that you might have to use EA on Linux and ADS on Windows.

Comment: Since you're talking about _image_ files, why not simply embed the tags inside the images themselves as [XMP metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Metadata_Platform)?